# How to upload images to s3 presigned URL in flutter?

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3

I create a s3 presigned URL in typescript as below:

```
const params = {
      Bucket: myBucketName,
      Key: uuidv4(),
      Expires: 3600,
    };
s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params)
```

and I used below code in flutter to upload image to this url:

Option1:

```
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "file":
          await MultipartFile.fromFile(image.path, filename: "upload.png"),
    });
    var response = await Dio().put(url, data: formData);
```

Option2:

```
return Dio().put(
      url,
      data: image.openRead(),
      options: Options(
        contentType: "multiple/form-data",
        headers: {
          "Content-Length": image].lengthSync(),
        },
      ),
      onSendProgress: (int sentBytes, int totalBytes) {
        double progressPercent = sentBytes / totalBytes * 100;
        print("upload $progressPercent %");
      },
    )
```

in both cases I got `403` forbidden error response. How can I upload images to the presigned URL? Is there anything wrong in the generated side or flutter side?

I can upload the file with `curl` command like below:

```
 curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  --data-binary "@/Users/Pictures/IMG_4634.jpg" $PRESIGNED_URL
```

so the url does work.

Comment: Does the IAM user that the app uses has permission to put objects into S3?

Comment: Yes, it has permission. I am able to upload the file via `curl` command. I have added curl command in the post

Answer (score 6):

I have tried all the solutions in this thread but it's not working

finally i found this blog: https://icircuit.net/flutter-upload-file-to-aws-s3/2885

this is the solution that works great with Dio:

```js
Future<Response> sendFile(String url, File file) async {
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  var len = await file.length();
  var response = await dio.put(url,
      data: file.openRead(),
      options: Options(headers: {
        Headers.contentLengthHeader: len,
      } // set content-length
          ));
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I created this class to send an single image to s3 using pre-signed url, I'm using camera lib to send a photo to s3.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';

class AwsApi {
  Future<String> uploadToSignedUrl({required XFile file, required String signedUrl}) async {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(signedUrl);
    var response = await put(uri, body: await file.readAsBytes(), headers: {"Content-Type": "image/jpg"});

    return response;

  }
}
```

You can change `await file.readAsBytes()` to this `file.readAsBytesSync()`, if you are using File

Comment: can u pls tell me value of signedUrl?

Comment: @RahulZx: I guess it is simply a signed url from AWS S3. Please take a look at this link for more details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: Error : `Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 941:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 81:22                                       <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 846:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 875:13`

Answer (score 3):

I was getting 403 doing the same thing with presigned s3 urls and had to use a `POST` request which returned a 204 and successfully saved the file.

Using the http package I did the example like so:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

```
var req = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(s3Url));
req.files.add(
  http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
    'file',
    file.readAsBytesSync(),
    filename: filename,
  )
);
var res = await req.send();
print('UPLOAD: ${res.statusCode}');
```

This returns a `StreamedResponse` type so to get the body of the response you need to convert the response.

NOTE: I did have to add a lot of fields on the multipart request like `AWSAccessKeyId` and `x-amz-security-token` which I was returning from the s3 presigned URL response. I configured it very securely though so you may not need that but wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If you can print the response from S3 somehow, that may reveal the error.

From the information available, I think the problem is that your are using a PUT request and not a POST request. Looking at the Dio documentation, it seems like you can use `Dio().post`. You may also need to set `Content-Type` like in your curl example.

If it still doesn't work, try adding `-v` to your curl command to see all of the headers it sends. It would be useful to get the network request that Dio sends, to compare against.

Comment: I have tried post and put but both doesn't work. After some searching and I found a solution for that. I have posted it on the answer. Please let me know if you have any comments on that solution.

Answer (score 2):

After some debugging, I found that this code can be used to fix it:

```
http.put(entry.value, body: image.readAsBytesSync())
```

I don't need to specify any header or any fields. And `http.post` is google enough to solve the issue.